# Discrete Ito Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, discrete-time

Let $W_t$ be a $d$-dimensional random-walk (here $t=0,1,\dots)$ and suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a twice continuously-differentiable function.  Does a "discrete" Ito Lemma of the form hold
$$
f(W_{t+1})-f(W_{t})= -\sum_{i=1}^d\frac1{2}\partial^2_{i,j} f(W_t) + \sum_{i=1}^d\partial_{i}f(W_t)W_t?
$$

If not...what would it look like?

Comment: The proof os Ito's formula starts with a discrete version using mean value theorem (in its integral form).

Comment: Maybe more interestingly, there's Proposition 1.13.1 of
https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642023798
which is a type of discrete-process Ito Lemma based on the Clarke-Ocone formula of Malliavin calculus (if you're familiar with that sorta thing).

Comment: @WillM.  What would be a good reference for this?

Comment: @AIM_BLB I just looked and the lemma you posted is very interesting but it only deals with Martingales so I'm not sure if it helps in the general (non-Brownian) case.

Comment: @WillM. There's a subtle difference here... Simple processes take on finite values but are defined in continuous time whereas discrete-time is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$.  The two constructions do not coincide.

Comment: @WillM. Also the discritization result has a remainder, aka an error term of quatratic ordre in the mesh-size... So the result is non-explicit.

Comment: I say with integral form, so there is no remainder. But the integral does need s continuum of values

Comment: This sounds interesting, but could you provide some more details please?